# HttpPost parameters not working

Tags: php, android, http-post

I have to make some client-server requests for my app. It works, but I can't read the posted parameters in my server with PHP. There are no errors or exceptions. I've tried lots of different ways, but it still just does not work.

```
   private class NetworkProvider extends AsyncTask<NetworkingParams, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(NetworkingParams... networkingParams) {
            String url = networkingParams[0].getUrl();
            String methodName = networkingParams[0].getMethodName();
            JSONObject params = networkingParams[0].getParamJSON();
            InputStream inputStream;
            HttpPost httpPost;
            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            String result = "inputStream is null";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {
                params.put("method", methodName);
                params.put("uNameDecoded", uNameDecoded);
                params.put("uPassDecoded", uPassDecoded);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            httpPost = createPostForJSONObject(params, url);

            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            try {
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                if (inputStream != null)
                    result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                return result;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        private HttpPost createPostForJSONObject(
                JSONObject params, String url) {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(createStringEntity(params));
            return post;
        }

        private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            String result = "";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                result += line;

            inputStream.close();
            return result;
        }

        private HttpEntity createStringEntity(JSONObject params) {
            StringEntity se = null;
            try {
                se = new StringEntity(params.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                System.out.println("error creating entity");
            }
            return se;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if the parameters are being sent as part of the body of the request? Did you check if the parameters are being well received by the server that uses PHP? Could you log any (including wrong) POST request made to your PHP app?

Comment: The parameters are inside httpClient. The server does not get any parameters. I was able to log a request. The server response works but the wrong data is coming back.

Comment: Add a break point at `se = new StringEntity(params.toString());` or log the content of `params.toString()` before creating the `HttpPost` element, just to check that you're sending the data in right format. Also, again, check through a proxy or another method how the request is being done. If this *works as expected*, then the problem may be in your PHP app. Use a RESTful service tester app like DHC for Chrome to test your PHP service.

Comment: I guess this was the problem. In php, I get this body content: '{"method":"isServer"}'. It shouldn't be JSON. This would be correct: 'method=isServer'. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the data was sent to the server in JSON format, which is not usual for PHP's $POST. Instead of using 'POST', I now use 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'. Works perfectly.
This is how I debugged the PHP post request body:

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $entityBody;
```

The structure for PHP $POST should be like this: 'a=value'. Not '{"a":"value"}'.
The Java code was correct.